# How to get database version via root user

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I am able to get the version of database as oracle user.
Any way i can get database version via root user?

Comment: What do you think a "root" user is in the Oracle world? A simple `select * from v$version` or `select version
from product_component_version
where product like '%Database%';` can be done using any Oracle user

Comment: Are you trying to get the Oracle version via the 'root' user of the OS without actually logging into Oracle ?

Comment: Yes. @BriteSponge there are 4 databases in my server. Just wanted to know if there's any place i can check in to get the versions without having to log in to all the instances.

Comment: If you are talking about 4 instances of the same ORACLE_HOME then all of them will report the same Oracle version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL:

`SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing using the recommended OFA guidelines the you can look at the directory path name of the Oracle install.
For example you may have something like;

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2
```

Obviously the database running from that structure could in fact be another version. However, if you don't want to log in and get the info (you only have 4 so not that onerous really) then this might be the way to go.